# Getting the default root directory in Java

Tags: java, file, browser

I'm making a basic file browser, and want to know how to get the default root directory. I know that `java.io.File.listRoots()` gives all the roots (for me it's `A:\, C:\, D:\, E:\, F:\, G:\, H:\, I:\, L:\ T:\, U:\, X:\, Y:\, Z:\`), but I want the one the user uses primarily (i.e. the one with the Operating system on it) so I know from where to start the browsing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Getting the operating system root partition is only a thing on `Windows` since on `Unix` it's always `/`.

Hence, the following code works for `Windows` only:

```
System.getenv("SystemDrive");
```

It gets the `SystemDrive` environment variable value. This should always return the operating system's root partition e.g. `C:`.

Answer (score 20):

Not sure if this is of any help, but you could try:

```
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;

FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getRoots()[0];
```

or

```
FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory();
```

or

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

For the last snippet, you could get the root directory by navigating upward using getParent() until `null` is returned.

Comment: @IanGilham I think you meant to comment on another answer

Comment: Yes, my bad. You seem to have found the one I meant.

Comment: `String userDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getAbsolutePath();

String rootDir = userDir.substring(0, userDir.indexOf(File.separator)+1);`

Comment: Downvotes because `System.getProperty("user.dir");` does not always return an OS drive path, rather the application's directory.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza is right. Perhaps that was meant to be `"user.home"`?