# Is there a way to get Root Directory in Java in a given File

Tags: java

Background

I'm creating an upload file functionality. I want to save the file in a given folder ("/uploadFiles"). I am currently testing in Windows but will run it in Linux.

I know I can get the current working TOMCAT directory. Is there a way to get the root system directory of TOMCAT directory? Say if the current directory is "D:\apache\sample_web_project" it will get "D:\" then I can append the "D:\uploadFiles" then if its in Linux it will get "/etc/apache/sample_web_project" it will get "/etc"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the default root directory in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362786/getting-the-default-root-directory-in-java)

Comment: This is quite a bad practice to store anything in `/etc` other than configuration files

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do that.

You should run Tomcat as a user, and then use its home directory as a base to store your files. Ie:

```
final Path downloadPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "uploads");
Files.createDirectory(downloadPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Path root = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getFileSystem()
            .getRootDirectories().iterator().next();
```

On ubuntu it returns `/`